# Can i attune a magic item to another player without their knowledge somehow?

Tags: magic-items

I've attached an item to a fellow player that attracts monster (apparently) but I want it to attune to him without his knowledge. (Because he would just back out of fights and stand away) my dm tells me that it wont do anything unless its attuned.

Edit: is Dungeons and dragons

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. This question will be put on hold until you [edit] it to add a tag indicating the game (and if applicable, edition) you're playing. Tags structure our database of questions for sorting and searching, so correct tags are necessary to attract experts and to help future users with the same question (a core part of the Stack's mission).

Comment: Which edition of Dungeons & Dragons? If you’re not sure, the covers of the *Player’s Handbook*s for each edition are listed in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editions_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Attunement is a mechanic specific for 5e. Knowing that, is it fine to include the tag, or should we wait for the OP anyway?

Comment: Well, on a second thought the DM could have made a house rule for attunement in earlier editions, so I guess it's better to wait for OP to clarify it anyway. I **guess**.